# EJB lookup fails during startup but is fine when the call is made after the server is started

Tags: jboss7.x, ejb-3.1

I am using `Jboss EAP 7.1`. And i managed to deploy a stateless `EJBbean` successfully. I am also able to access the deploy `EJB` after the server is started successfully.

```
    final Hashtable jndiProperties = new Hashtable();

    jndiProperties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");

    jndiProperties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

    jndiProperties.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", true);

    Context context;

    try {

        context = new InitialContext(jndiProperties);

        String appName = "";

        if ("FlowControllerBean/remote".equalsIgnoreCase(jndiName)) {

            appName = "";


        } else {

            appName = "upm-0.1";

        }

        final String distinctName = "";

        String beanName = "";

        final String viewClassName = FlowController.class.getName();

        System.out.println(
                "ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!" + viewClassName);

        if ("".equalsIgnoreCase(interfacename)) {

            context = new InitialContext();

            return context.lookup(jndiName);

        } else {

            beanName = jndiName.substring(0, jndiName.indexOf("/"));

            return context.lookup("ejb:" + appName + "/" + moduleName + "/" + distinctName + "/" + beanName + "!"
                    + interfacename);

        }

    } catch (NamingException e) {

        // TODO Auto-generated catch block

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

    return null;
```

But my real problem comes when i want to access the same `EJB` during server start up itself. One of my method inside a service bean calls this EJB Bean during server start up itself. But it fails with the message

> "EJBCLIENT000079: Unable to discover destination for request for EJB
>
> StatelessEJBLocator for "/ejb-remote-server/FlowControllerBean", view
>
> is interface com.hexaware.framework.flowcontroller.FlowController,
>
> affinity is None".

Before the lookup is executed the actual EJB beans are deployed. Please find below the logs from server before the lookup is made during start up.

> 14:36:25,971 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4)
>
> WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment ejb-remote-server.jar
>
> 14:36:26,373 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread
>    1-4) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named
>
> 'FlowControllerBean' in deployment unit 'deployment
>
> "ejb-remote-server.jar"' are as follows:
>
> java:global/ejb-remote-server/FlowControllerBean!com.hexaware.framework.flowcontroller.FlowController
>
> java:app/ejb-remote-server/FlowControllerBean!com.hexaware.framework.flowcontroller.FlowController
>     java:module/FlowControllerBean!com.hexaware.framework.flowcontroller.FlowController
>     java:jboss/exported/ejb-remote-server/FlowControllerBean!com.hexaware.framework.flowcontroller.FlowController
>     java:global/ejb-remote-server/FlowControllerBean
>     java:app/ejb-remote-server/FlowControllerBean
>     java:module/FlowControllerBean
>
> [org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ServerImpl] (MSC service thread 1-4) Setting
>   the server's publish address to be
>   http://localhost:8080/ejb-remote-server/EventManagerService
>   14:36:29,409 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.cxf.deployment] (MSC service thread
>   1-4) JBWS024074: WSDL published to:
>   file:/D:/Magesh/Softwares/Jboss-eap-7.1/standalone/data/wsdl/ejb-remote-server.jar/EventManagerServiceService.wsdl
>   14:36:29,643 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-4)
>   WFLYWS0003: Starting service
>   jboss.ws.endpoint."ejb-remote-server.jar".EventStatusService
>   14:36:29,650 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (MSC service thread 1-2)
>   WFLYWS0003: Starting service
>   jboss.ws.endpoint."ejb-remote-server.jar".EventManagerService
>   14:36:30,197 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService
>   **Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: '/ejb-remote-server' for server 'default-server'**

But the same code works if i call it after the server is started completely.

Below is my property file which i have used for connecting from the client to my remote server.Both server and client are in same Jboss server instance in my local machine.

> remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
>
> remote.connections=default
>
> remote.connection.default.host=localhost
>
> remote.connection.default.port = 8080
>
> remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false

**Note: Look up is successful during start up or any other time. But when i try to call a method in the bean the error message is encountered. But same bean method call works after server start up**